# How can I let users share their location in Bot Framework webchat channel?

Tags: botframework

I read that you can share location with the backchannel.

I was thinking to use this code to talk directly to the bot:

```js
function postButtonMessage() {
        botConnection.postActivity({
            entities:{type: "ClientCapabilities", requiresBotState: true, supportsTts: true, supportsListening: true},
            from: { id: 'userid', name: 'username' },
            name: 'botname',
            type: 'message',
            value: 'Hi',
            textFormat: 'plain'
          })
          .subscribe(function (id) {
            console.log('"buttonClicked" sent');
          });
      };
```

But I get an error saying "bad gateway 502", but when I talk through the web channel windows it works perfectly so I know that the direct line key is configured correctly. And when I use the type: `event` instead of `message` it works fine and I don't have problems, so I am confused about that.

(Question originally asked at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/778#)

Comment: So you want to know how to use backchannel or what?

Comment: I am using backchannel but just for events... i have implemented my bot in a web but now we need to send the current location of the user gps coordinates. In facebook we are using a button to send location and only works in facebook, but in web i dont know what are the posibilities to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches here.

One is to use the *backchannel* to send an `event` activity to the bot with whatever data you like. You could do this when a button is clicked, at regular intervals, or whenever the location changes.

```
var dl = new BotChat.DirectLine({secret});

BotChat.App({
    botConnection: dl,
    // other Chat props go here
});


function postButtonMessage() {
    dl.postActivity({
        from: { id: 'userid', name: 'username' },
        type: 'event',
        name: 'location',
        value: { /* location goes here */ }
      })
    .subscribe(id => {
        console.log('"buttonClicked" sent');
    });
};
```

The other is to use *client middleware* to send that data with every message, by intercepting and modifying each message as it goes out. The advantage to this approach is that each message is 'tagged' with its location. The disadvantage is that you only get location updates when the user sends a message.

```
var dl = new BotChat.DirectLine({secret});

BotChat.App({
    botConnection: {
        ... dl,
        postActivity: activity => dl.postActivity({
            ... activity,
            channelData: { location: /* location goes here */ }
        })
    },
    // other Chat props go here
});
```

And of course you could do both!

Comment: Hi Bill - there was [discussion on Meta a while back about the quality of questions in the Bot Framework tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357645/can-we-work-with-microsoft-to-improve-the-quality-of-questions-theyre-referring). In cases where you refer a question from GIthub over to here, it would be great if you can try to help make sure the poster understands the level of detail expected for an on-topic Stack Overflow question. That said - thanks for working to help support the community!

Comment: @SamHanley actually I was thinking about that this morning and totally agree. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries! Just thought I'd mention it here since in its original form, this question was highly likely to be closed. Thanks for helping to edit it into shape - I made a few further grammatical edits and approved your edit suggestion. It's appreciated!